# Case insensative search/filter in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, sqlite, django-views

### at my Search class of django project
I try to get products query from db but it case sensative
not matter what i tried, i still can not enhance my search query
maybe not that way to solution, i will find a possible way to get it right
but one and biggest broblet that i use Sqlite3 wher is method `(name__icontains=search_query)`
not valid, i mean valid but does not work

part of Search class:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        search_query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        print(f"start q {search_query}")
        print(Product.objects.filter(name__icontains=search_query))
        print(repr(search_query),"----------")
        if search_query:
            # Filter products where label contains the search query (case-insensitive)
            return Product.objects.filter(name__icontains=search_query)
        else:
            return Product.objects.none()
```

Answer (score 1):

The __icontains filter should work for case-insensitive containment tests. It could be some setup issues that might affect its behavior.

You can use custom SQL to enforce case-insensitive search. Django's ORM allows you to execute raw SQL queries, which can be helpful in situations where the ORM's capabilities are insufficient.

```
from django.db import connection

def get_queryset(self):
    search_query = self.request.GET.get('q')
    if search_query:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM your_product_table WHERE name LIKE %s COLLATE NOCASE", [f"%{search_query}%"])
            result_list = cursor.fetchall()
        # Convert the result_list to QuerySet if necessary
    else:
        return Product.objects.none()
```

Try that custom code and see, if its working, also you could try to increase the logging level to see the actual SQL queries being generated and executed.

This might give you more insight into what's happening under the hood. Django's logging can be configured to show all SQL queries in the console.

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('django.db.backends')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

Once we have this insight we could further apply fixes.

Comment: Looks good, but i need to try it for check speed and big O notation.
Maybe it better for enhence search logic in future manualy

Answer (score 0):

Solution so simple
`name__icontains=search_query`
not work in my case cause of using Sqlite3 but...
`name__iregex=search_query` make it all good
now search case-insensative :)